# Do skill increases and perks increase the dual wielding attack speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

From my recent experiences with a new dual-dagger wielding character, I noticed that repeatedly slashing with a single dagger seems to be equally fast as slashing alternately with two daggers being dual-wielded, and the simultaneous attack with both daggers (M1 + M2 tapped at the same time, not a power attack) was only slightly faster (counted as two strikes, one with each blade). Does dual wielding become noticeably faster late-game from skill increases and perks, so that a player desiring a very high attack rate would choose it over a single dagger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Dual Flurry Perk, dual wielding attacks are 20% faster for the first rank and 35% for second rank.  Until you get this perk, dual wielding is no faster than a single weapon.

Comment: Does this affect alternate attacks with the dual-wielded weapons, or just the simultaneous attack with both? In practical terms, is 35% noticeably faster than the default, comparable to Elemental Fury on a weapon?

Comment: @Thaumajig - the first word of elemental fury increases attack speed by 50%.  I think 35% is very noticeable.  The effect should apply to all attacks made while dual wielding, but I cannot confirm this 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Berserker for an orc increases damage and attack speed, and dual-wielded weapons while on Fury with an orc will help, so make sure if you're in heavy combat you are an orc or have Agility trained.

Comment: Hello, Mitchell, and welcome to gaming! I'm not sure if this is an answer to the question, as the information seems to be referring to some other game. Agility is not a stat in Skyrim, and Berserk does not increase attack speed at all. Would you care to provide some clarifying infO?